# CopyFolder giving issues

Tags: vbscript

I know my Admin rights work. I can copy the files using Explorer with no issues.

Here is my code

```
softwareFolder = "X:\Software\app\2.0" 
shortcutFolder = "X:\Software\app\SKYNet"

pcName = "\\\\" & pcName & "\\c$\\scripts\\2.0"

Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFolder softwareFolder , pcName
```

I am trying to copy a folder to  **\\PCNAME\c$\scripts\2.0**

I am getting Path not found

Comment: Have you tried to print the contents of the variables to make sure they contain what you expect?

Comment: If VBS, you don't need to escape the path character. so `pcName = "\\" & pcName & "\c$\scripts\2.0"`.

Comment: I didnt realize that. But even after fixing the escape character problem, I still get PATH not found. I suspect the destination path doesn't exist but shouldn't the CopyFolder create it if it didn't exist?